# Bourbon Neat -- responsive grid

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bourbon, neat

Ive looked at the examples for [Bourbon Neat](http://neat.bourbon.io/examples/) responsive grid. To my knowledge I'm using it correctly.

**Issues**

- the `<div>` tags all take up their own line as if I had made them all
  `span-columns(12)`

My guess is that I am not nesting the elements correctly or I should be using tags such as `<section` or `<aside>`

**The following is what I have so far in order to learn this responsive framework ...**

`application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LawRails</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= render "layouts/header" %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

`header.html.erb`

```
<div class="contain-header">
<div class = "last-names">Attorney & Attorney</div>
<div class = "contain-eight">
<div class = "street-address">250 W. Main Street Suite 9999</div>
<div class = "city-state-zip">City, US 30399</div>
</div>
</div>
```

`header.css.scss`

```
.contain-header {
    @include outer-container;
    .last-names {
        @include span-columns(4);
    }
.contain-eight {
    @include span-columns(8);
    .street-address {
        @include span-columns(4 of 8);
    }
    .city-state-zip {
        @include span-columns(4 of 8);
    }
}
}
```

`application.css.scss`

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "neat";
@import "welcome";
@import "layout";
```

As previously mentioned. The divs all take up their own full line. I would like to learn how to make this all one line with separation as the css suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your code should work. See gist here: http://sassmeister.com/gist/d8f0c7ffa3ff16e93b8a

My guess is that you are not properly importing neat and/or bourbon.

**In your `application.css.scss` make sure that you @import "header"**

- Since that is the css sass file you are using with bourbon neat to position your elements